# Not until structure

Tags: sentence-meaning

The following sentence contains inverted word order in the main clause:

> Not until that evening was she able to recover her self-control.

It sounds like a question. But there is no question mark at the end of the sentence. What is actual meaning of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a question.  It is synonymous with:

> Not until that evening she was able to recover her self-control.

and

> Until that evening she was not able to recover her self-control.

and

> It was not until that evening that she was able to recover her self-control.

Comment: or "She was not able to recover her self-control until that evening."